# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting will not use an INDEX/MATCH formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office

I have a table that uses the following formula to pull data from two other tables:
`=IF(INDEX(InitASIPTable,MATCH([@[EFH JST]],InitInspJST,0),MATCH(HeaderRow,TailNumberRow,0))="INITIAL CW",INDEX(SortieTime[CW-13R],MATCH(HeaderRow,SortieTime[Tail],0)),INDEX(InitASIPTable,MATCH([@[EFH JST]],InitInspJST,0),MATCH(HeaderRow,TailNumberRow,0)))`

Basically, it looks at the first table to see if an initial inspection has been completed.  If yes, it goes to the second table to pull the recurring inspection remainder time, if no it provides the remainder until the initial inspection.  The issue I'm having is getting the conditional formatting in Excel 2010 to highlight the cells in the table to show me if the time I'm seeing is being pulled from the initial table or the recurring table.  I have 12 rows x 15 columns within this table that I'm trying to lay this formatting on.

I've tried using this formula for the conditional formatting:
`=ISNUMBER(INDEX(InitASIPTable,MATCH([@[EFH JST]],InitInspJST,0),MATCH(HeaderRow,TailNumberRow,0)))`
However, Excel rejects that formula with a "The name that you entered is not valid" error message, even though when I drop that formula in the middle of the table it correctly returns "TRUE" or "FALSE."

I've also tried explicitly defining every range and while Excel accepts the rule, it doesn't apply the conditional formatting.  Here's the modified formula that Excel is accepting:
`=ISNUMBER(INDEX('SHEET 1'!$G$5:$U$16,MATCH($A$2:$A$13,'SHEET 1'!$A$5:$A$16,0),MATCH($D$1:$R$1,'SHEET 1'!$G$2:$U$2,0)))`
Defining the ranges here:
`Sheet 1 G5:U16` is the initial time data table
`A2:A13` is the [EFH JST] column (the unique key) in the table to be formatted
`Sheet 1 A5:A16` is the initial table's JST column
`D1:R1` is the header row for the table to be formatted
`Sheet 1 G2:U2` is the header row for the initial data table

Any time I drop that formula into the middle of the table it correctly returns true or false, so I know the formula works here.  Am I trying to process a formula more complicated than Excel can handle here or am I missing something else?

Comment: I modified the question based on the answer from Kieran, however I'm still not getting the appropriate formatting applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this same question over the the MSDN Technet Forums, the answer that finally fixed the issue was to set the conditional formatting to be `=SUMPRODUCT((InitASIPTable=D2)*1)>0`.  It's not a solid fix as it depends on both tables never having identical values, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use table references in the conditional formatting formula ie. [@[EFH JST]]

You can try saving the formula to a named range and then using that

Comment: That's what I thought too, so I removed all table references named ranges and explicitly defined every single range (i.e. ='sheet1'!A1:C1).  All it does at that point is place the formula inside quotes and treats it as a text string instead of evaluating it.

Comment: That sounds like something else going wrong, is the original error still happening?